# How do i get an authentication token into a Rails 2.2.2 application that uses restful authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

Our rails 2.2.2 application uses [restful authentication](https://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/classic). We would like to use an authentication token in an email link but i see no provision for an authentication token in the documentation on the original or subsequent versions of restful authentication. Am i missing something or is there a workaround?

Edit: To use Devise instead i would need to upgrade to rails 2.3 which I would prefer not to do because it breaks some elements of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a month without a response on this question, I upgraded to Rails 2.3.11 and then replaced restful authentication with [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) which will generate an authentication token.